# How to close TextPrompt after a certain time if the enduser doesn't reply

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, botframework

In Microsoft chatbot SDK v4 I want to know how to programmatically close the Prompt "any type of it TextPrompt, ConfirmPrompt ... etc" and end the dialog after period of time if the user didn't reply.

I already tried to use settimeout and use sc.endDialog but it doesn't work and gave me

```
private promptForNameStep = async (step: WaterfallStepContext<UserProfile>) => {

setTimeout(async () => {
   console.log('I am here!');
   await step.endDialog();
}, 5000);

        const userProfile = await this.userProfileAccessor.get(step.context);

        if (userProfile.name === undefined) {
            // prompt for name, if missing
            return await step.prompt(NAME_PROMPT, i18n.__('salutation.your_name'));
        }
        return await step.next();
    }
```

```
(node:21084) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked
    at UserState.load (/Users/macbook/Workspace/bot/chatbot/templates/Enterprise-Template/src/typescript/enterprise-bot/node_modules/botbuilder-core/src/botState.ts:84:48)
    at BotStatePropertyAccessor.get (/Users/macbook/Workspace/bot/chatbot/templates/Enterprise-Template/src/typescript/enterprise-bot/node_modules/botbuilder-core/src/botStatePropertyAccessor.ts:97:43)
    at SkillDialog.getStateFromAccessor (/Users/macbook/Workspace/bot/chatbot/templates/Enterprise-Template/src/typescript/enterprise-bot/src/dialogs/skill/skillDialog.ts:164:68)
    at SkillDialog.executeStep (/Users/macbook/Workspace/bot/chatbot/templates/Enterprise-Template/src/typescript/enterprise-bot/src/dialogs/skill/skillDialog.ts:91:47)
    at Array.stepsMethods.push (/Users/macbook/Workspace/bot/chatbot/templates/Enterprise-Template/src/typescript/enterprise-bot/src/dialogs/skill/skillDialog.ts:149:29)
    at WaterfallDialog.onStep (/Users/macbook/Workspace/bot/chatbot/templates/Enterprise-Template/src/typescript/enterprise-bot/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/src/waterfallDialog.ts:198:44)
    at WaterfallDialog.runStep (/Users/macbook/Workspace/bot/chatbot/templates/Enterprise-Template/src/typescript/enterprise-bot/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/src/waterfallDialog.ts:225:31)
    at WaterfallDialog.resumeDialog (/Users/macbook/Workspace/bot/chatbot/templates/Enterprise-Template/src/typescript/enterprise-bot/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/src/waterfallDialog.ts:166:27)
    at WaterfallStepContext.endDialog (/Users/macbook/Workspace/bot/chatbot/templates/Enterprise-Template/src/typescript/enterprise-bot/node_modules/botbuilder-dialogs/src/dialogContext.ts:269:33)
    at <anonymous>
(node:21084) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
(node:21084) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I expect that the dialog closed but I got the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Using a timeout to end the conversation is not a good practice because when you scale out messages may be routed to different instances of the bot and the timeout won't be canceled correctly. A better approach is to save the last time the user messaged the bot in userState and check the time difference the next time the user messages the bot before responding. Take a look at the code snippets below.

```
const TIMEOUT = 5000;

...

 // Prompts
  async promptForName(step) {
    this.profileAccessor.set(step.context, { lastMessage: new Date() });    
    return await step.prompt(NAME_PROMPT, "What is your name?");
  }

  async captureName(step) {
    const profile = await this.profileAccessor.get(step.context);
    if (new Date().getTime() - new Date(profile.lastMessage).getTime() < TIMEOUT) {
      profile.name = step.result;
      profile.lastMessage = new Date();
      this.profileAccessor.set(step.context, profile);

      await this.userState.saveChanges(step.context);

      return await step.next();
    } else {
      await step.context.sendActivity("Sorry, you took too long to respond");
      return await step.endDialog();
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a good idea in case I am going to only depend on the enduser input to response so it will move to the next step but some other cases the user never reply and I want -for example- to update some reports or send data to analytics tools in the end of dialog event so I want to find a way to close it programmatically.

Comment: Did you git my comment @tdurnford

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56675385/10708483). I answered it with this one in mind.