# How can I send the proactive message after 2 min of clicking on GetStarted button in facebook

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

How can I send the proactive message after 2 min of clicking on GetStarted button in facebook

```
async function getstartedinterval(dialogContext)
{


  timeoutobj= setTimeout(function (dialogContext) {
      console.log('--- inside setTimeout----',dialogContext);// displaying as undefined 
      notificationMsgGetStarted(dialogContext); 
  },constant.timeinterval);


}
```

I have tried with SetTimeOut but DialogContext is not accessible in this function. Please suggest .

Comment: setTimeout doesn't pass variables to the callback function by default. Try `setTimeout((param1, param2)  =>  console.log(param1, param2), ms, param1, param2);`

Comment: Take a look at this StackOverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190642/how-can-i-pass-a-parameter-to-a-settimeout-callback

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried but its not working. Hence, I used delay npm package. some how my requirement completed through that package. thanks.

Comment: it has been resolved using delay npm package. thanks.